# Umbraco - will members remain when copying from test to live

Tags: umbraco

I have two umbraco websites; test and live. I'm making updates to the content through umbraco on the test site and will push that to live via sql 2014 when I copy the database over. Users can login to view the website.

What I'd like to know is, will the members who have joined the live site in the meantime be lost when I overwrite the live database with the test database? Will the test website members data overwrite the live site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes unfortunately they will be.  All members are contained in the Umbraco database so if you overwrite the live database with your test database you will of course lose anything in that database.

If you are using Umbraco 7 your best bet would be to purchase [Umbraco Courier](http://umbraco.com/products-and-support/courier/) which will allow you to merge the changes in your local copy to the remote copy. This would be the most straightforward option in my opinion.